# Can we use Kibana as a log monitoring tool for an application running in weblogic?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana

My use case is: I have a java application running in a weblogic. I want to monitor this applications log in real time. The log is created using log4j. Is it possible to use Kibana or configure Kibana to monitor these logs in real time.?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, but just that Kibana needs that log data. You export/load that log data either using `Filebeat` or `Logstash` into Elasticsearch. Use Kibana to set up watchers, alerts etc to prompt you your `400s`, `401s`, `500s` error codes etc.

Not sure if you have Elasticsearch cluster built already, but Kibana works with Elasticsearch (not directly on logfile's machine).

Comment: Thanks @JBone, We dont have an Elasticsearch installation. Actually we have a java application with customized logs. Can we configure Logstash or elastic search how to read those custom log files. I'm new to all these, just wanted to know the possibilities.

Comment: @arun_hareesh, it will be a significant effort to do this. You have to build Elastic cluster (that also includes Kibana instance). Once this is up and running, have `Filebeat` to ship the log file(s) into Elasticsearch. You will also have to do some Index Lifecycle Management tasks etc.. I would recommend start getting familiar with Elastic first (ILM, indexing etc) esp `installation guide` and `getting started guide` from here 
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html